# how to change default behavior of make

Tags: compiler-construction, compilation, makefile

heyho,

I want to change the default behavior of "make".
I want it to run the following commands when compiling a c file:

**clang *file*.c -std=c99 -Wall -Werror -fcolor-diagnostics -lcs50 -lm**

is there a "nooby" way to do so?

thx in advance,

tom

---

if searched the forums and tried google - nothing came up. but chances are, that i did not know what exactly to search for... so if this is answered somwhere else, I'm realy sry...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this into your bash start-up script:

```
export CC=clang CFLAGS="-std=c99 -Wall -Werror -fcolor-diagnostics" LDLIBS="-lcs50 -lm"
```

Better is to put these lines in your `Makefile` (for simple cases, you don't need anything more, but you probably want to add dependency lines):

```
CC=clang
CFLAGS=-std=c99 -Wall -Werror -fcolor-diagnostics
LDLIBS=-lcs50 -lm
```

Even better is to create a proper `Makefile`, but the above will get you started.

You can create a `Makefile` with any text editor. `make` looks in the current directory for the `Makefile` (which is usually called `Makefile` but it can also be called `makefile`). Just put it in the same directory as the `C` program.

Comment: thanks very very much.
i actually wanted to create a makefile - and allready had found the cflag command. this reported, that there was "no makefile" found.
where can i create such a makefile (where to put it how to create one...)
i found whole lot (the gnumake man) about the syntax, but not how to create one and where to put it. create i guess is just gedit - put where do i put it? do i have to tell make where they are found?

Comment: @LeTigre, a Makefile is simply a text file; you can create it with any text editor. It is most convenient to name it `makefile` and put it in the directory in which you will run `make` (e.g. the directory that contains `file.c`). If you do otherwise, you must tell Make where it is (`make -f path/to/the/makefileName`).

Comment: @LeTigre, like beta said. I added a para to the answer.

Comment: this is great - thank you very much.
i'd love to give you points - but i'll have to earn reputation first it seems

Comment: i now added it to .bashcr and will use (now that i know how...) makefiles for more special occasions like programming bigger things in one folder.

i realy appreciated the help! thx again! - it works like a charm!

Comment: @LeTigre. Thanks. I noticed that I had written `LDFLAGS` where it should have been `LDLIBS` so I fixed it.